# How to remove xcode warning in macports?

Tags: macports, osx-mountain-lion

I have this warning in macports:

```
Romans-iMac:~ holms$ sudo port -v install nginx +ssl
Error: 
Error: No valid Xcode installation is properly selected.
Error: Please use xcode-select to select an Xcode installation:
Error:     sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode45-DP1.app/Contents/Developer # version 4.5
Error:
```

Although I already used that command, warning is not disappearing, and compilation works anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like there are two problems going on. First, and this one's silly, you might not have accepted the XCode license agreement (See http://www.xensoft.com/?q=node/3).

To solve this issue, just try:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license # Press 'q' then type 'agree' to accept the license agreement
```

Secondly, the version of MacPorts installed may still be verifying XCode's installation by looking for some directories that have been re-arranged in XCode 4.4. There's a patch for this that looks like it will roll out with MacPorts 2.1.2. Or now, if you're using your own Macports build using the trunk branch of the MacPorts `svn` repository. (See https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35150).

Comment: ok problem was that it's old macport version, and only svn version  can normally support mountain lion, as it's not stable..